# Is a transient entity with id set still a transient entity or a detached entity

Tags: hibernate

By definition, a newly instantiated POJO, say `transientPerson`, is a transient entity.

```
Person transientPerson = new Person();
```

An entity detached from persistent context is a detached entity.

```
Person detachedPerson = session.get(Person.class, id);
session.detach(detachedPerson);
```

After setting all the fields of `detachedPerson` into `transientPerson`, is `transientPerson` still a transient entity?

```
transientPerson.setId(detachedPerson.getId());
transientPerson.setName(detachedPerson.getName());
```

If this is the case, does it mean that I'm able to use `persist(transientPerson)` to update the corresponding table in DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between transient and detached entity is whether that entity really has the corresponding record exist in DB. Transient entity does not have but detached entity has (See the official definition at [there](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc)).

So in this case, `transientPerson` technically will become detached as there are really a DB record exist for it.

And calling `persist()` on the entity that already exists in the DB (i.e detached entity) will throw `EntityExistsException`. You have to use `merge()` to insert or update the detached instead.